# What is the path of your app internal storage folder

Tags: android

I made many folder in my internal storage; for example,

```
    folder1 = getBaseContext().getDir("Bussiness Folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;

    folder2 = getBaseContext().getDir("Home Folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;

    folder3 = getBaseContext().getDir("Date Folder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
```

Now I want to know what folder these folders (folder 1,2,3) are located. What is the path to the folder that these folders are located? Basically - what is the path of your app internal storage folder?

Below Code did not give the path of this folder. . .

```
    String path = getFilesDir().getPath();
```

Comment: what `getFilesDir().getPath()` return when running code?

Comment: "Below Code did not give the path of this folder" -- yes, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code gives slightly different path of this folder:

```
String path = getFilesDir().getPath();
```

the path of this file ends with files but this is different. But my problem is solved. I toasted the path and hard coded the path in.